# Sentry's sourcemaps/artifacts don't work

Tags: webpack, sentry

I'm building, minifying and generating sourcemaps of my app with webpack. Artifacts are sent to sentry.io with webpack-sentry-plugin.

The javascript code is run from `localhost:8080/js/app.js`. It contains `//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map` at the end. Sourcemaps work correctly at Chrome devtools.

Sentry's Releases/Artifacts contain the following files:

```
js/app.js
js/app.js.map
```

Anyway, when Sentry logs an error, stacktrace is from the minified file. It's not using the sourcemaps.

What am I doing wrong in my setup? Or what other info should I give to get help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted this question at forum.sentry.io and got the answer from a guy called @benvinegar.

Here is the thing: when sending a sourcemap/artifact, we provide the file and also a filename. The filename is meant to be the complete URL where the sourcemap would be located if it was uploaded to the host together with the minified JS files. That is: if our minified Javascript is located at `www.example.com/js/app.js`, then the sourcemap/artifact filename must be `www.example.com/js/app.js.map`. Otherwise, we can name it `~/js/app.js.map` if we want the sourcemap to apply to other situations like running the app at `localhost:8080/js/app.js`.

As I'm using `webpack-sentry-plugin`, it was just a matter of adding the following property to the plugin:

```
{
  plugins: [
    new SentryPlugin({
      filenameTransform: filename => '~/' + filename
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like that filenameTransform is now the default for `webpack-sentry-plugin`: https://github.com/40thieves/webpack-sentry-plugin/commit/e3edd4b5211d9fb1edf921f180c71212f8881d06

Comment: In my case, I was missing the path to my file.

`'~/static/javascripts/' + filename`

Comment: I am using webpack in backend file to generate a single bundler file (main.js)

Answer (score 4):

In our case, it hasn't been working for a loooong time.

Everything seems to be just fine. Artifacts uploaded, versions tagged, errors logged, but no sourcemaps.

Bottom line of the issue: We are hosting Sentry ourselves and sentry is divided into different containers. They did not properly share the data.

One solution is to share the data between containers (see [that post](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-node/issues/435#issuecomment-371859277)) or to even upload your sourcemaps to an S3 server and Sentry can also work with that.