# Raven doesn't use source maps in Sentry for TS/JS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sentry, raven

I already used Sentry in a C# project and was very pleased about it. So I also want to use it in a new NodeJS project with TypeScript. Sadly, the required sourcemaps doesn't work fine here. I first tried it in a plain TS project without success. Even in a plain raw JS project it doesn't do any source code mapping.

For the test project, I exactly followed the documentation on node/sourcemaps:

- https://docs.sentry.io/clients/node/config/
- https://docs.sentry.io/clients/node/sourcemaps/#webpack
- https://docs.sentry.io/clients/node/typescript/

The result is always the same, Sentry shows me the ugly code without using sourcemaps:

[image: Sentry ignores Sourcemap]

It seems that Sentry doesn't use the sourcemaps for unknown reasons cause the corresponding Release contains the required sourcemap:

[image: Artifacts of Release]

I spend a lot of hours on this. Tried several things, including different paths/file names for the files pushed to sentry. I also used the Sentry cli tool directly, to make sure, that there is no issue with the webpack plugin. Nothing works, Sentry always shows me the raw source code and ignores the sourcemap.

The following files are from my second nodejs program using plain raw JavaScript. It's as minified as possible to work. I don't know whats wrong here cause I did exactly what the documentation requires.

### What is the problem?

Sourcemaps were generated and uploaded. First I thought that the file names/paths doesn't match. [This older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089443/sentrys-sourcemaps-artifacts-dont-work) shows a similar issue, where the paths doesn't match since they were not relative using `~/` but in `SentryPlugin` this is the default prefix. On the other side, `dataCallback` make sure that all paths are relative to the project root, instead of having absolut paths like `/home/user/project/dist/app.js` which would be the default behavior. I did a `console.log` there to see that they're correctly relative.

### Simple NodeJS test project using plain raw JavaScript

#### src/app.js (Main programm)

```
var Raven = require('raven')
const path = require('path')

let options = {
    release: process.env.RELEASE,
    dataCallback: function (data) {
        var stacktrace = data.exception && data.exception[0].stacktrace;
        if (stacktrace && stacktrace.frames) {
            stacktrace.frames.forEach(function (frame) {
                if (frame.filename.startsWith('/')) {
                    frame.filename = 'app:///' + path.basename(frame.filename);
                }
            });
        }

        return data;
    }
}
Raven.config('http://<DnKey>@<SentryHost>:9000/3', options).install();
//Raven.captureException(new Error('abc'))

throw new Error('Hello123')
```

#### webpack.config.js

In this file, I changed the entry path from `src/app.js` to `./src/app.js`. The Sentry docs use `./src/app.js` but this result in an error that the path cannot be resolved. It appears to be an mistake of the docs.

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const SentryPlugin = require('@sentry/webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        "app": './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new SentryPlugin({
            release: process.env.RELEASE,
            configFile: 'sentry.properties',
            include: './dist',
            ignore: ['node_modules', 'webpack.config.js'],
        })
    ]
};
```

#### sentry.properties

I added the configFile attribute since `SentryPlugin` uses internally the CLI of Sentry. The CLI needs to know some information like url or auth-token from Sentry. This could be passed as environment variables, but I like the approach of using a config file, which is completely valid according to the docs. Token has project.write permission as required.

```
defaults.url=http://SentryHost:9000
defaults.org=sentry
defaults.project=js-test
auth.token=xxx
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "sentry-js-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist/* && webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/cli": "^1.30.2",
    "@sentry/webpack-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "raven": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10"
  }
}
```

#### Start the test programm

```
export RELEASE=3.0.20 && npm run build && node dist/app.js
```

This use webpack to minify `src/app.js` and place the minified version in `dist/app.js`. Furthermore, it creates a sourcemap called `dist/app.js.map`.

On every run, I changed `RELEASE` (e.g. increment to 3.0.21). That's important since Sentry assumes, that releases and source files (also sourcemaps) are a 1:1 relation. So if we upload our files to release with version 3.0.20 this is done on the first time. On the second time, the files keeps unchanged cause the cli sees that they're already existing. Using a new version make sure that our latest changed files are always uploaded and we don't mess with old ones from playing around.

I spend a lot of hours on this issue and have no Idea what I'm doing wrong. Summarized, I did every step from the tutorials of the documentation, with some small fixes on obvious errors.

#### Information about the environment

I'm using self hosted Sentry 8.22 in docker containers on Arch Linux. NodeJS is used in Version 9.7.1.

Comment: If you've find a solution ever since please share it :) Facing the same issue...

Comment: @maxime1992 Sadly no. My experience is that TypeScript isn't as powerfull/stable as C# with ASP.NET Core and in the meantime Microsoft improved the framework and released ASP.NET Core 2. So we moved to ASP.NET Core, where sentry work well in 5 minutes without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

After months struggling with that we finally found the issue.

You can see that the artifacts are here with the sourcemaps, that you correctly tag the versions and everything seems fine?

Running Sentry on your own I bet? We are too.

Well that's the issue.

Sentry is divided into different services and in order to have them sharing the data (sourcemaps...) you need to share a volume between them. Please read [that post](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-node/issues/435#issuecomment-371859277) where it's correctly explained.

Also, if you prefer, you can host them on S3 and Sentry can work with that too!